# Predicate in realm with dictionary parameters

Tags: swift, dictionary, realm, predicate

I want to create a predicate with a dictionary paramateres and filter data on realm, like

```
var parameters = [String: Any]()
                        parameters["Mobile"] = a.Mobile!
                        parameters["CategoryId"] = self.SelectCategryId

                        let existContact = (contactBiz.FetchMulti(parameters: parameters)?.count)! > 0
```

and in fetchMulti func I make a predicate and filter data

```
func FetchMulti(parameters: [String: Any])-> Results<RealmEntityType>?
{
    do
    {
        let key = T.KeyName()

        var object = realm.objects(RealmEntityType.self)

        let subPredicates = parameters.map {
            NSPredicate(format: "%@ = %@", $0.key, $0.value as! CVarArg)
        }

        let compoundPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: subPredicates)


//            var predictionArray = [String]()
//            for p in parameters
//            {
//                predictionArray.append("\(p.key) = \(p.value) ")
//                 
//            }
//            
//            let perdicate = predictionArray.joined(separator: " && ")
//            


        return object.filter(compoundPredicate);
    }
    catch
    {
        print(error.localizedDescription)

    }
    return nil

}
```

but I get this error

```
 reason: 'Predicate expressions must compare a keypath and another keypath or a constant value'
```

Any help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `%K` to indicate that the value is the name of a key and not a constant string: `NSPredicate(format: "%K = %@", $0.key, $0.value as! CVarArg)`